# MySQL Query returning all dates instead of specified year and month clauses

Tags: php, mysql

The code below returns all dates in the table as if the month and year clause did not exist. However if I don't store month and year as variables and just use a constant date, then it works fine. How is this possible? Thanks.

```
$m="01";
$y="2015";

$get_my_dates = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dates WHERE YEAR('$y-01-01') = $y AND MONTH('2000-$m-01') = $m");
while($result = $get_my_dates->fetch_object()){
      echo $result->date."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `WHERE YEAR('$y-01-01') =$y` is asking MySQL to compare the value of `$y` with the YEAR of a date built using `$y`..... that will always match... and you're doing the equivalent with month.... you might as well simply do `WHERE $y =$y`, or even `WHERE 2015 = 2015`

Comment: you don't really have conditions here. It's same with `SELECT * FROM dates`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at what you're doing:

```
WHERE YEAR('$y-01-01') = $y ...
```

That's going to evaluate to:

```
WHERE YEAR('2015-01-01') = 2015 ...
WHERE 2015=2015 ...
WHERE TRUE ...
```

and **ALWAYS** evaluate to true.

You need to check the dates of the records in your table, e.g.:

```
WHERE YEAR(datefield) = $y AND MONTH(datefield) = $m
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because your query's WHERE clause is meaningless.  Your WHERE conditions will ALWAYS be fulfilled because you are not checking the field values at all, but rather the input values you are giving.

You should do the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dates
WHERE your_date_field >= '$y-$m-01 00:00:00'
AND your_date_field < '$y2-$m2-01 00:00:00'
```

Here `$m2` would be set to `$m1 + 1` and `$y2 = $y`, unless of course `$m` equals 12, in which case you would need to increment `$y2 = $y + 1` and set `$m2 = 1`.

Note that I wrote the WHERE clause this way instead of the more simple looking

```
WHERE YEAR(your_date_field) = $y
AND MONTH(your_date_field) = $m
```

because the former would be able to use an index on the field, whereas the latter would not and would require a full table scan.

Comment: @user2014429 Glad to help.  You should also consider using prepared statements for this query instead of concatenating your variables directly into the query.

Comment: i will do, this is just a rough mock up